# Custom property attribute

Tags: c#

Consider the following function, it simply generates an Sql UpdateCommand for an Object

```
public static string UpdateCommand<T>(this T obj,string idPropertyName, List<string> Except = null, List<string> Only = null)
{
    List<PropertyInfo> properties = FilterPropertyList<T>(Except, Only);

    StringBuilder query = new StringBuilder();
    query.Append("UPDATE " + typeof(T).Name + " SET ");
    for (int i = 0; i < properties.Count; i++)
    {
        if (idPropertyName.ToLower() == properties[i].Name.ToLower()) 
            continue;
        query.Append("[" + properties[i].Name + "] = @" + properties[i].Name + ",");
    }
    if (properties.Count > 1) 
    { 
        query.Length -= 2; 
    }
    query.Append(" WHERE " + idPropertyName + "=@" + idPropertyName);
    return query.ToString();
}
```

the second parameter is just the property name which refers to the property name that represents the primary key in the Sql table, i was wondering if its possible to represent that property with an attribute that would be available in the property info, this way i wont have to send it as a parameter.

if this was my object

```
public class SomeObject
{
    //add a custom attribute to the id so it would be recognized in the above function without having to send the property name as a parameter
    public int id {get;set;}

    public string name {get;set}

}
```

the following is how i use the function with a SomeObject instance

```
var someObject = new SomeObject();
var someObjectUpdateCommandString = someObject.UpdateCommand<SomeObject>("id");
```

can i use some built in attributes, or is it better to create my own attribute?
Here is my try, not sure if its write and i cant seem to use it

```
[AttributeUsage(AttributeTargets.Property, AllowMultiple = false)]
    class IsPrimaryKey : Attribute
    {
        public IsPrimaryKey()
        {
            this.isPrimaryK = true;
        }

        private bool isPrimaryK;
        public virtual bool IsPrimaryK
        {
            get { return isPrimaryK; }
            set { isPrimaryK = value; }
        }
    }
```

Comment: Do you call it like `someInstance.id.UpdateCommand("Table_id", ..., ...)` ?

Comment: @OndrejJanacek no someinstance.UpdateCommand("primarykeycolumnName" ,...,...) i just wrote an attribute but can figure out how to use it, the sql table name is the same as the object name, so if object was called xx then the sql table name is xx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The name of the attribute class should end with the `Attribute` suffix.

Generally, it is a good idea to reuse existing annotations, if they have exactly the purpose that you are looking for, and don't pull unnecessary dependencies.

In your case, the [`System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations.KeyAttribute`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.dataannotations.keyattribute.aspx) attribute, added in .NET 4.0, would probably fulfill the purpose you are looking for.

Comment: seems like it was a dependency problem, when i moved the attribute to the library that i want to use it in it worked fine...spent hours figuring what i did wront but in the end nothing was wrong